# singular point of a complete intersection surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $S:= H_1\bigcap H_2\bigcap \cdots \bigcap H_N \subset\mathbb{P} _{\mathbb{C}}^{N+2}$ be a complete intersection surface, where each $H_i$ is a hypersurface defined by a homogeneous equation $f_i$.

If $x\in S$ is a singular point of $H_i$ for some $i$, then $x$ is a singular point of $S$.

My question is: Is it possible that there is a point $x\in S$ such that each $H_i$ is smooth at $x$ and $S$ is singular at $x$?
Can you give a reason for your answer?

Comment: Of course. Let $H_1 \subset \mathbb{P}^3$ be a smooth quadric surface and $H_2$ a tangent plane to $H_1$. Then $H_1 \cap H_2$ is a pair of intersecting lines.

See Roy's answer below.

Answer (score 4):

this is not a research level question.  a point on an intersection is singular if either it is singular on some one of the intersecting varieties or if those varieties are tangent at some point.